The character who can only fall in love once
I remember about a character from a movie or a TV show which was an alien I believe, and he fell in love with another character and we learned that this alien species's heart was made to fall in love only once for the rest of their life.
I don't even know why I tought about this but the fact I can't remember about the movie/tv show is driving me nuts.

It might have been either sci-fi or superhero movie/show and I don't know if the character was the main character.
It was made after the year 2000
It was in colour
It was in English

But I don't remember any faces, or when was it set and neither where.
Sorry if I'm not specific enough but I barely remember about this.
I hope I'm going to find an answer.

There's a Star Trek TNG episode that is similar to this... but I don't know that it's what you're looking for.

@Catija No It isn't, I litteraly never saw any star trek show or movies (don't blame me, I'm not into this much sci-fi) But thanks for trying to help !

Perhaps you're looking for I am Number Four? This fits the plot details of it being a superhero type film. The main character, John Smith, is an alien from the planet Lorien and one of the distinguishing factors of these aliens is that they can only fall in love once. From here: 

Imagine knowing with absolute certainty that you’d met “the one” at age 16. That’s what it was like for Number Four, aka John Smith, when he encountered the lovely Sarah Hart. You see, Loriens don’t love like the humans — when they fall in love, it’s forever. Lucky for him, she seemed pretty into him, too.


Yes that's it ! Thank you ! I remember now ! Thanks, I enjoyed this movie tho.

I saw this question in the review queue and immediately knew the answer. Have a +1 for getting there first ;-)

Star Trek the Next Generation had this episode were Picard ends up being involved with an alien empath Kamala who is bound to 1 person for the rest of their life. It's as you describe, tho only a few years sooner. The episode is called The Perfect Mate
